# C# EventHandler returns null when called

Tags: c#, events, delegates, eventhandler

I have a two classes.In one class i am creating and raising an event as follows :

**CustomerAdd Class**

```
public class CustomerAdd
{
public delegate void Done(object Sender, EventArgs e);
public event Done ListUpdated;

public void UpdateNewList()
{
 //adding items to a generic List<T>,code removed as not relevant to post
 //and raising the event afterwards

 if (ListUpdated != null)
 {
  ListUpdated(this, EventArgs.Empty);
 }
}
}
```

**MyWindow Class**

```
public class MyWindow
{
private void SaveToDisk()
 {
  CustomerAdd cuss = new CustomerAdd();
  cuss.ListUpdated += new CustomerAdd.Done(DisplayDetails);
  cuss.UpdateNewList();
 }
 private void DisplayDetails()
 {
  //other codes here
 }
}
```

Now, when i call the `SaveToDisk` method from `MyWIndow` class,(as i am subscribing `DisplayDetails` method to the `ListUpDated` event) , `DisplayDetails` is not called. The debugger shows that `ListUpdated` is null. I have searched for hours and failed to come up with a solution.I followed [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d4bac5bb-affb-4339-b748-1b375fcb5c54/can-someone-help-me-of-using-event-handler-in-c-with-simple-example-?forum=csharpgeneral) but still `ListUpdated` is null. Any guidance/help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `DisplayDetails` must have `CustomerAdd.Done` signature:
`private void DisplayDetails(object Sender, EventArgs e)`

Comment: @ДмитрийШулицкий , no luck , the method is not called

Comment: Why are both classes named `CustomerAdd`?

Comment: @ДмитрийШулицкий, sorry , edited now

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you create a new Delegate when there is already a framework provided one for that signature (EventHandler) ?

Comment: @Crowcoder , yeaj, good question ... the reason i did is because i had been using `EventHandler` till now with the same issue , so i thought creating my own delegate may result in my favor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {

        public class CustomerAdd1
        {
            public delegate void Done(object Sender, EventArgs e);
            public event Done ListUpdated;

            public void UpdateNewList()
            {
                //adding items to a generic List<T>,code removed as not relevant to post
                //and raising the event afterwards

                if (ListUpdated != null)
                {
                    ListUpdated(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                }
            }
        }

        public class CustomerAdd
        {
            public void SaveToDisk()
            {
                CustomerAdd1 cuss = new CustomerAdd1();
                cuss.ListUpdated += new CustomerAdd1.Done(DisplayDetails);
                cuss.UpdateNewList();
            }
            private void DisplayDetails(object Sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Test");
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var c = new CustomerAdd();
            c.SaveToDisk();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was dumb enough.... the problem was that i was subscribing to the event after i called the method(the post in my code definitely works, but it is not the original code... ) so , thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CustomerReceive cr = new CustomerReceive();
            cr.SaveToDisk();

        }
    }

    public class CustomerAdd
    {
        public delegate void Done(object Sender, EventArgs e);
        public event Done ListUpdated;

        public void UpdateNewList()
        {
            //adding items to a generic List<T>,code removed as not relevant to post
            //and raising the event afterwards

            if (ListUpdated != null)
            {
                ListUpdated.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }

    public class CustomerReceive
    {
        public void SaveToDisk()
        {
            CustomerAdd cuss = new CustomerAdd();
            cuss.ListUpdated += new CustomerAdd.Done(DisplayDetails);
            cuss.UpdateNewList();
        }
        private void DisplayDetails(object Sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int k = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

You need to do a good read on delegates and events because this is not working when there are more listeners

Comment: am i not doing the same thing ?